# Why do I get error: problem decoding CoreML document?

Tags: swift4, xcode9, coreml

I am using CoreML with Swift 4.0 on Xcode 9 Beta.

If you select a file `VGG16.mlmodel` in the Project navigator, I get an error: `There was an problem decoding this document CoreML`

In addition, as a consequence in the code I get the errors `Use of unresolved identifier 'VGG16'` and `Use of undeclared type 'VGG16'`

**VGG16.mlmodel** downloaded from here https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/

What could be the problem?

PS for models Places205-GoogLeNet, ResNet50 and Inception v3 everything works fine.

Comment: The example project can be found here https://medium.com/towards-data-science/welcoming-core-ml-8ba325227a28 , https://github.com/alaphao/CoreMLExample

Comment: I don't know the answer (maybe the VGG16.mlmodel was not downloaded correctly?) but you don't want to use VGG16 on a mobile device anyway. It's way too big (500+ MB), way too slow, and eats up way too much energy.

Comment: I downloaded this model from the apple website several times.
Maybe on the Apple website the file is broken...
Yes, I know that the size of this model is very large.
So say research interest.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans & A.Kant  - I get a similar error with VGG16 as well. The download seems to be broken. So I thought I will try with something else and downloaded Inception v3. I added the .mlmodel file to my project and I can see it display fine in XCode (Not the decoding error as I get with VGG16). But when I try to use it in my code, var inceptionEngine: Inceptionv3?, var inceptionEngine: Inceptionv3?inceptionEngine = Inceptionv3(), I get error 'Use of undeclared type 'Inceptionv3''. Can you pls guide me on how to import these models and use in the code?

Comment: @csharpnewbie - Make sure your .mlmodel file is actually part of your target (select it, open up the inspector on the right side of Xcode, and make sure the checkbox for your target is selected). I noticed that the Xcode 9 beta sometimes doesn't include your model in your target when you add it to your project. It doesn't auto-generate the proper header if the .mlmodel isn't in your target.

Comment: @BradLarson, Thank you so much. I did not notice that the target was not selected.

Comment: @BradLarson Hey, Brad. Your answer was correct. Making it a full answer and I will choose it as true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As requested, I'll flesh out my comment into an answer.

Others have mentioned this, but you most likely have a corrupted download or there's something broken with the model itself. To begin with, I highly recommend not using the VGG16 model or related models on a mobile device just due to their sheer size (500 MB for VGG16). You'll exhaust memory on an iPhone 6 just loading the model, your application size will be gigantic, and you'll have a lengthy initialization time as those weights are loaded.

I recommend using something like a SqueezeNet variant, which is small (~5 MB), can be more accurate when trained on ImageNet, and isn't as computationally expensive as the Inception family. Apple makes reference to using one of these in one of the Core ML WWDC sessions.

When you add the model to your Xcode project, make sure it is actually being registered with your target. The current beta of Xcode occasionally forgets to add this to your target, so highlight the model and check in the file inspector to make sure it is part of your application target. If the model isn't in your target, Xcode won't auto-generate the Swift header for it.

Comment: Actually I had both of these problems: 
First, when you download from the apple site https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/ model file VGG16.mlmodel were cut at 250-270 MB.
You can download the model VGG16 here - https://yadi.sk/d/DLr99UZs3KGJqu
Secondly, you really have to tick to add the model in your target.
In addition, on iPhone 6 (IOS 11 beta) this model runs very slow and heats phone.
Thank you, Brad (@BradLarson).

Comment: @A.Kant - As far as speed goes, at least in the initial beta it appears that Core ML uses Accelerate's BNNS operations, not Metal, to execute these networks on the iPhone 6. In a benchmark I ran, on an iPhone 6 Core ML was roughly 3.5X slower when running a stock AlexNet vs. the exact same network implemented on the same device using Metal Performance Shaders. Not sure why it doesn't use the MPS operations on the iPhone 6, since the hardware clearly supports them.

Comment: Or they will support MPS on the iPhone 6 in the next version, or is that apple encourages us to buy a new iPhone :)
@BradLarson

Answer (score 2):

1. pls run `./setup.sh`
2. select target for `VGG16.mlmodel`, see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6G8U.png)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing for a model that has Dropout on it. Try removing these layers by copying weights over to new model without them.